# Is it safe to delete Log Analytics Workspace

Tags: azure, logging, azure-devops, monitoring, azure-aks

I have an AKS cluster setup. In that subscription I also have a *Log Analytics Workspace*. As this is a pretty huge cost factor and I think I'm not actually using it, I thought about deleting it. But I cannot find any information if it is safe to do so.

I don't care about the data saved in it. Neither metrics nor logs. I have separate Elastic and Prometheus stacks running in the cluster for logging and monitoring.

But as I can't remember actively creating the resource, I'm not sure whether this is somehow vital to AKS and will break my setup when being deleted.

In case it is not, will deleting it affect any other resources (temporarily)? Like restarting VMs, or something like that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its absolutely fine deleting the workspace. As per the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/logs/delete-workspace#permanent-workspace-delete) you can soft delete or permanent delete the work space.

> In case it is not, will deleting it affect any other resources
> (temporarily)? Like restarting VMs, or something like that?

No it wont effect any other resources. As log analytics workspace is a unique environment and it can be created to monitor those resources which have deployed for a long time.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Deleted the resources and everything seems fine. Thanks :)